Expansion for source block not working in org mode
This blog post is from 2013 and it mentions version 8. It says that entering <s will insert the source block
#+BEGIN_SRC 
#+END_SRC

Then it gives other expansions, for instance, <q for quotes.
These expansions do not work in my emacs 9. Are they discontinued?

That was removed long time ago, and placed in snippets as <src.

@Ian I use #+BEGIN_QUOTE #+END_QUOTE a lot. How do I enter this as a snippet?

Surprisingly <q is also defined as snippet and works ok. I use the latest version of yasnippet-snippets.

yasnippet is not the only way - see my answer below. Also, note that <q has to be followed by TAB to activate (both in the legacy code and in the org-tempo case currently).

There is a new mechanism, but the old mechanism still works (with some changes). There are various ways to provide template expansion currently:

use yasnippet as @Ian mentions in the comments.

(require 'org-tempo) and use <s, <q, etc. (followed by TAB) just as in the earlier version, but there are a few limitations: single-letter abbreviations only, whereas (IIRC) the earlier version allowed multiple-letter abbreviations. Also the old placeholders (like %file) no longer work.

use C-c C-, (bound to org-insert-structure-template), whose advantage is that it can "wrap a region": you can e.g. yank some text into your Org mode file and say C-c C-, to put  the block delimiters at the beginning and end of the yanked block (this is the "new" way: available since version 9.2, released December 2018 or so).


The last two both use org-structure-template-alist so you can add new entries to extend the mechanism. But note that the structure of it has changed, so don't go modifying it without reading the current doc string (that's the danger of reading blogs from 2013).
Look in the Release Notes file under Version 9.2 for the changelog:
*** Change in the structure template expansion

Org 9.2 comes with a new template expansion mechanism, combining
~org-insert-structure-template~ bound to ~C-c C-,~.

If you customized the ~org-structure-template-alist~ option manually,
you probably need to update it, see the docstring for accepted values.

If you prefer using previous patterns, e.g. =<s=, you can activate
them again by requiring Org Tempo library:

: (require 'org-tempo)

or add it to ~org-modules~.

If you need complex templates, look at the ~tempo-define-template~
function or at solutions like Yasnippet.



Thank you. Tempo option works great for me. Cursor stays inside the quote block.
